# Lightning Datatable fixed header overlap in android

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, salesforcedx, lightning-datatable, android

I have a lightning Datatable fixed header, but it is overlapping in Android as in the image attached below and it work's fine in iPhone and Desktop. Any work around for this issue?

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVfto.png)

Answer (score 1):

Hi For fix this issue u simply need to add  **z-index:1;** into styling array of you Header.

```
<th  style="position: sticky; top: 0;z-index:1;" >
```

and boom it will resolve your issue. Please try and let me know if it is working for you